# Table padding in LyX

Tags: tables, spacing, lyx

I'm creating in LyX a table wich has a single character for every cell. Problem is, a lot of space is wasted, because each cell has some padding points which I'd like to reduce.
A cell is now big enough to contain 3 characters, but I need them to be a little bigger than the character itself. Ideal objective is to get all the cells square shaped of equal size.

A screenshot is attached to let you understand what I'd like to accomplish (they are not really regular as my drawing skills are poor :P)

I tried with this thread [Column and row padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-padding-in-tables) but without luck: cells are still wide.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance
~Aki

[image: A table with reduced padding and square cells]

Comment: Have you tried reducing the value of `\tablecolsep`, which equals (half) the width of the whitespace between columns? Its default value is `6pt`. Try `\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}` for starters. Separately, you may also want to consider eliminating the vertical rules between columns entirely; when you have a lot of columns, these rules tend to take up a lot of space while not adding appreciably to the table's readability.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows your current code, and perhaps the adjustments you've made after reading [Column padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-padding-in-tables).

Comment: Mico, thanks, it did it. If you write a reply I'll check it as answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may want to change the value of `\tabcolsep`, a length variable that equals (half) the width of the whitespace that separates columns. You use the command `\setlength` to change the value of this length variable. The default value of this variable is `6pt` (if the main text's font size is 10pt); a value of `3pt` will give you a rather tightly-set group of columns.

Separately, you may also want to consider eliminating the vertical rules between columns entirely. When one has a lot of columns, the vertical rules tend to take up a lot of space while not adding appreciably to the table's readability.

The following code and the associated image illustrate the effects that reducing the value of `\tabcolsep` from 6pt to 4, 3, and 2pt has. In all cases, I've eliminated all vertical rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\newcommand{\quicktabular}{%  this construct will be used several times
\begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}
\toprule
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J \\
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Default value of \texttt{\textbackslash tabcolsep} (6pt)

 \quicktabular

\item \texttt{\textbackslash tabcolsep} = 4pt
 \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}

 \quicktabular

\item \texttt{\textbackslash tabcolsep} = 3pt
 \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}

 \quicktabular

\item \texttt{\textbackslash tabcolsep} = 2pt
 \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}

 \quicktabular

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Insert *before* the table with Ctrl-L for "Evil Red Text" and write `\begingroup\tabcolsep=0pt\def\arraystretch{0}`. *After* 
the table do the same, hit CTRL-L and write `\endgroup`. Then you do not have any space left and right of your entry

Comment: Shouldn't the second instruction be `\def\arraystretch{1}`?

Comment: no it shouldn't

Comment: +1 for actually answer the question (of how to solve this problem in LyX).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to place code in LyX, but the following should do what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newlength{\mystrutht}
\newcommand{\mystrut}{\rule{0pt}{\mystrutht}\rule[-1pt]{0pt}{1pt}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\hbox to 1em\bgroup\mystrut\hfil}c<{\hfil\egroup}}
\newenvironment{zerotabular}
  {\settoheight{\mystrutht}{A}\addtolength{\mystrutht}{1pt}%
   \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}%
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
   \begin{tabular}}
  {\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{zerotabular}{|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
A&A&C&G\\
\hline
C&A&A&C\\
\hline
A&C&A&A\\
\hline
\end{zerotabular}
\end{document}
```

The first part (between the `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}` lines) should go in the preamble code.

Each cell is typeset in a box as wide as to accommodate a capital M; interline spacing is suppressed and substituted by a hand made strut that's 1pt higher and deeper than a capital letter.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but actually using a new environment discard the table-composing GUI features available for lyx (at least I think). Using \renewcommand with \tabcolsep don't require to change the LyX code, so I'll go with it as a "preferred" (i.e. more adapt with the UI) solution. Thanks anyway for this interesting example, which I'll study for my interest outside the LyX scope :)