# Table too wide to go out of the page.

Tags: tables, lyx

I have a table, which seems to be too wide for my page and it pops out of the page border.
In lyx, it is like[image: table too wide to get out of the page]

And in PDF, it looks like, it is going out of the page border.
[image]

How can I address such issue ?

Comment: Does [this quesion](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94579/how-to-edit-tables-in-lyx) help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click a cell in the right column, and choose More --> Settings. Under *Column settings*, set the Width to a specific value. This will enable line breaking in that column.